# java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.api.GradleException for spring-core-6.0.2.jar

Tags: gradle

I am getting below error while building the gradle:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file C:{folder path}\.gradle\caches\jars-9\4d6cded054513435538f8c1f816f4acb\spring-core-6.0.2.jar.
```

How to resolve this issue?

I tried building the gradle project and a lock file is getting generated for `spring-core-6.0.2.jar`

I am using `jdk17` and `Spring Boot version 3.0`